# Failed to instantiate module ui.tree due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'moduleName' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I am working on a AngularJS application where I am displaying data using a third party library called [angular-ui-tree](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree).
In order to use this library I should add `ui.tree` as a dependecny to my main app module. I have done all the steps given in that link in order to use this library.
I have successfully used this library to create the tree I want. Now I would want to write jasmine specs for my controller.

But after using this library, none of my previous jasmine specs are working.
All the jasmine are throwing the error as follows.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module CqAdminUiApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.tree due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.tree' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.tree
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:2082:17
    at ensure (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:2006:38)
    at module (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:2080:14)
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4617:22
    at forEach (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4601:5)
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4618:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4601:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=ui.tree&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ui.tree'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dui.tree%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2082%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2006%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2080%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4617%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4618%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4640:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4601:5)
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4618:40
    at forEach (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4601:5)
    at Object.createInjector [as injector] (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4523:19)
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js:3074:52)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1942:24)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=CqAdminUiApp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20Failed%20to%20instantiate%20module%20ui.tree%20due%20to%3A%0AError%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'ui.tree'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dui.tree%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2082%3A17%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ensure%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2006%3A38)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20module%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A2080%3A14)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4617%3A22%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4618%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.8%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dui.tree%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520Module%2520'ui.tree'%2520is%2520not%2520available!%2520You%2520either%2520misspelled%2520the%2520module%2520name%2520or%2520forgot%2520to%2520load%2520it.%2520If%2520registering%2520a%2520module%2520ensure%2520that%2520you%2520specify%2520the%2520dependencies%2520as%2520the%2520second%2520argument.%250Ahttp%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.5.8%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dui.tree%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A68%253A12%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A2082%253A17%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520ensure%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A2006%253A38)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520module%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A2080%253A14)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A4617%253A22%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A321%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A4601%253A5)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A4618%253A40%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520forEach%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A321%253A20)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520loadModules%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8234%252Fwebjars%252Fangularjs%252F1.5.8%252Fangular.js%253A4601%253A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4640%3A15%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4618%3A40%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4601%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.createInjector%20%5Bas%20injector%5D%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular.js%3A4523%3A19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.workFn%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.8%2Fangular-mocks.js%3A3074%3A52)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20attemptSync%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8234%2Fwebjars%2Fjasmine%2F2.5.1%2Flib%2Fjasmine-core%2Fjasmine.js%3A1942%3A24)
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4640:15
    at forEach (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:321:20)
    at loadModules (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4601:5)
    at Object.createInjector [as injector] (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js:4523:19)
    at Object.workFn (http://localhost:8234/webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js:3074:52)
    at attemptSync (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1942:24)
    at QueueRunner.run (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1930:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1915:10)
    at Spec.queueRunnerFactory (http://localhost:8234/webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:710:35)
CqAdminUiApp routing should proceed to /Jobs on requests to /Jobs when logged in
```

The first few lines indicate that the module `ui.tree` might not have been added as dependency to the main app module. But I have made sure that it is added. 
I found several other posts on stackoverflow regarding this error, but all of them talk about adding the missing module as dependency to the main app which I have already done.
I am surprised that I still get the same error.
Blow is the code snippet.

**My Main App Module**:

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var MyUiApp = angular.module('MyUiApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngCookies',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ui.tree',
    'chart.js',
]);

MyApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/Authenticate', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/authenticate.html',
        controller: 'authenticationController'
    }).

    // configuration for other urls.
   }]);
}());
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/image/favicon.png"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/angular-chart.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webjars/angular-ui-grid/3.2.1/ui-grid.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/derp.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/spinner.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/blur.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/angular-ui-tree.min.css">   

    <script src="webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/favico.js/0.3.10/favico-0.3.10.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/chartjs/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="webjars/angular-ui-grid/3.2.1/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>    // This js file is required for ui-tree
    //Other files

</head>
<body ng-app="CqAdminUiApp">
    <div ng-controller="indexController">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                    <li class="sidebar-brand">Continuous Quality</li>
                    <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link4">Link4</a></li
                    <li><a href="#Logout">* Logout *</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                <div ng-view class="explode-animation"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using jasmine specs. The spec-runner.html is as follows.

**spec-runner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Derp-o-meter v1.0</title>

<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="assets/image/favicon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">

<script src="../webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/jasmine/2.5.1/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>

<script src="../webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-mocks.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angular-base64/2.0.5/angular-base64.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.14.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/favico.js/0.3.10/favico-0.3.10.min.js" ></script>
<script src="../webjars/chartjs/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angular-chart.js/0.8.8/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="../webjars/angular-ui-grid/3.2.1/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/angular-ui-tree.js"></script>           // This is the js file needed for ui-tree

<!-- include source files here... -->
<script src="../app/services/authenticationService.js"></script>
<script src="../app/services/eventsService.js"></script>
<script src="../app/controllers/eventsController.js"></script>
<script src="../app/controllers/indexController.js"></script>
<!-- include spec files here... -->

<script src="spec/controllers/eventsController-spec.js"></script>
<script src="spec/controllers/jobsController-spec.js"></script>
// other spec files

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

One of the jasmine specs file **spec.js**

```
describe('eventsController', function() {
    var scope, mockMyService;

    beforeEach(function() {
        angular.mock.module('my.services');
        angular.mock.module('my.controllers');
        angular.mock.module('mock.my.services');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, _mockMyService_) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        mockMyService = _mockEventsService_;
        $controller('myController', {
            myService: mockMyService,
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('should fetch products', function() {
        scope.$apply();

        expect(scope.products[0]).toBe("bat");
        expect(scope.products[1]).toBe("ball");
    });
});
```

Can someone help me get rid of the error described above.

Comment: Can you share the spec.js file (try to run only one of them, and share that one)

Comment: I added one of the specs.js file.

Comment: Not entirely sure, but can you add "beforeEach(module('MyUiApp'));" at the beginning of the spec, to make sure module is loaded? Worth a try.

Comment: I tried as you suggested. But still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you included all your source files (including the one that defined the main app module) in the spec-runner.html? I'm not sure I see them (only controllers/services are there)

Comment: Yes, I have them. I have just not included here on stackoverflow. Also, like is said, before I started working on this feature, all of the jasmine spec were working. Only after I started working on this feature, most of my specs started failing with the same error. There are around 8-10 specs out of 115 which are passing but the rest fail with the same error. Surprisingly, the specs file containing the tests for controller in which I added this new feature seems to pass though. I am not sure what is happening.

Comment: @RITZXAVI Hi, did you figure out what was the issue? Facing the same issue..

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and my problem was related to missing dependency in **karma.conf.js**:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html
'use strict';

// ...
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: '../../..',

        // testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
               'src/main/resources/webapp/lib/jquery/jquery.js',
               'src/main/resources/webapp/lib/angular/angular.js',

                // !!! This was missing:
               'src/main/resources/webapp/lib/angular-ui-tree/dist/angular-ui-tree.js'

               'src/main/resources/webapp/app/*.js',
               'src/main/resources/webapp/app/**/*.js',
        ],
        ...
    });
};
```